# Explode multiple string columns to rows

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that contains some ID data and 2 location columns that are strings separated by commas:

| ID | Country | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA,Mexico | California,Mexico City |
| 2 | Germany,France,Sweden | Munich,Paris,Stockholm |

I would like to explode these columns so that they become new rows:

| ID | Country | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | California |
| 1 | Mexico | Mexico City |
| 2 | Germany | Munich |
| 2 | France | Paris |
| 2 | Sweden | Stockholm |

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use a combination of :

- [arrays_zip](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip.html?highlight=zip#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip)
- [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html?highlight=explode#pyspark-sql-functions-explode)
- [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html?highlight=split#pyspark-sql-functions-split)

Assuming `df` is your dataframe :

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "data", F.explode(F.arrays_zip(F.split("Country", ","), F.split("City", ",")))
)

df.select(
    "ID", 
    F.col("data.0").alias("country"), 
    F.col("data.1").alias("city"),
).show()

+---+-------+-----------+
| ID|country|       city|
+---+-------+-----------+
|  1|    USA| California|
|  1| Mexico|Mexico City|
|  2|Germany|     Munich|
|  2| France|      Paris|
|  2| Sweden|  Stockholm|
+---+-------+-----------+
```